# How to show price shipping without tax in shipping method step Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I want to display price shipping without tax in shipping method step, I have configured it like this but it is not working. It still shows at price 4.40 while without tax is 3.70, please help me.

[image]
[image]

**Shipping method step it show 4.40**

[image]

**Cart and payment method it show 3.70**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the configuration on the store level?

Comment: hi  Sumit, Only 1 store